# Windows 7 x64 COM/Serial port Sniffer/Redirect

Tags: windows-7, terminal, serial-port

I need to know what's happening between my computer and a USB Virtual COM port device in order to understand if all of the bytes are being well transmited.

I use a Java application to interact with the device and I want to have a native app that allow me to see the exchanged frames (both ways), but I can't find any software for that in Windows 7 x64.

Is there any software to sniff ir just redirect a COM port received and trnasmitted messages?

Comment: Have you had any luck finding one yet on other sites?

Comment: I've found one that works, but it's not free: http://www.hhdsoftware.com/serial-monitor 

The rest only works with x86

Comment: This issue was discussed and have more answers in "Serial / Com Port monitor for Windows x64 [closed]"
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674553/serial-com-port-monitor-for-windows-x64